# Pythonic way to write cascading of loops and if statements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Maybe this is a super dumb question but I was wondering what is the pythonic way of write this conditions:

```
custom_field_labels = ['value1', 'value2']

def whatever(label):
    if label not in custom_field_labels:
        custom_field_labels.append(label)
    else:
        invalid_name = True

        while invalid_name:
            label += "_"
            if label not in custom_field_labels:
                custom_field_labels.append(label)
                invalid_name = False

whatever('value1')
whatever('value3')
print(custom_field_labels) # ['value1', 'value2', 'value1_', 'value3']
```

I've read about that recursion is a bad idea in python. Is that true? If yes, what are the other options?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I would like to append "_" into a string while it exists inside custom_field_labels. If not exists, just append the value.

Comment: @placplacboom Can you expand on that further? It still isn’t entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

You just need one `while` loop.

```
while label in custom_field_labels:
    label += "_"
custom_field_labels.append(label)
```

If `label` isn't in the list, the loop will never be entered so you'll append the original label; this is essentially the same as the first `if`.

I also recommend against the pattern

```
while boolean_variable:
    # do stuff
    if <some condition>:
        boolean_variable = False
```

Either test the condition itself in the `while` condition, or use:

```
while True:
    # do stuff
    if <some condition>:
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to append "_" into a string while it exists inside custom_field_labels.

Then do exactly that?

```
def whatever(label):
    while label in custom_field_labels:
        label += "_"
    custom_field_labels.append(label)
```

No idea why you're asking about recursion.

Comment: He's asking because it *could* be done with recursion: `else: whatever(label + "_")`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than store the almost-the-same labels directly, you can use a `Counter` object, and reconstruct the labels as needed.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(["value1", "value2"])
>>> c['value1'] += 1
>>> c['value3'] += 1
>>> c
Counter({'value1': 2, 'value2': 1, 'value3': 1})
>>> [x+"_"*i for x, n in c.items() for i in range(n)]
['value1', 'value1_', 'value2', 'value3']
```

(It would be nice if there were an `add` method so that `c.add(x)` was equivalent to `c[x] += 1`. Oh, well.)